# Using built-in wifi and not external adapter

Tags: wireless

I have an external wireless adapter TP-LINK TL-WN722N and have set it up. Now, it automatically connects to my WiFi network. I want to use the WiFi adapter that is built-in in my laptop and connect through it to my wifi network and not through the external adapter. Any help would be appreciated!

Note: I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/908385/edit) your question to include the output of `lspci -knn`.

Comment: Well, I think it was kind of easy. I managed to change that from the upper toolbar where I could choose with which adapter to connect to a network.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Network icon in the top panel and choose `Edit Connections`. Edit the wireless network profile of your choosing. Find the `Device` field, and select the popup, and choose the desired wireless adapter desired for that connection.